# protobuf-net deserialize fails when using ReadOnlyMemory

Tags: protobuf-net

I can deserialize when passing a stream, but if I pass a ReadOnlyMemory instance instead of a stream, I get a ProtoException "Invalid wire type (VarInt)"
Why?

Protobuf-net version 3.1.26

repro:

```
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var test = 1;
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, test);

            // save off bytes for later comparison
            var bytes = stream.ToArray();

            // this succeeds
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var item = Serializer.Deserialize<int>(stream);

            // this succeeds
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var item2 = Serializer.Deserialize(typeof(int), stream);


            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var rom = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(stream.ToArray());
            // sanity check: newBytes should be equal to bytes, and it is. 
            var newBytes = rom.ToArray();

            // this fails with ProtoException "Invalid wire-type (Varint)..."
            var item3 = Serializer.Deserialize(rom, typeof(int));
            
        }
```

Comment: My example code uses ReadOnlySpan but the result is the same with ReadOnlyMemory.

Comment: Intriguing. I'll need to look. Can you log it as an issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `Serializer.Deserialize<int>(rom)`? I wonder if your call is doing `Deserialize<Type>` via the second parameter being interpreted as an existing object.

If you need a non-generic API:

```
ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(type, rom);
```

Comment: To amplify on Marc's response: I was inadvertently invoking a method overload that was not what I intended.  In my  Serializer.Deserialize(rom, typeof(int)) , the second parameter matches the  "default value" parameter of an overload.  Somehow this syntax ends up trying to use the first parm, ReadOnlyMemory, as a stream. As he says, the solution is to use NonGeneric.Deserialize(type, rom)